# How to keep text within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic chat html page. When the user submits a message, I display the user's username, followed by a colon, followed by the message. If the message is really long, the text goes out of the div element. How do I prevent this? Here is the form.

```
   <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div id="chatArea">
        </div>
        <form role="form" id="userInput">
            <button id="endChat" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Esc</button>
            <button id="sendMessage" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="messageArea"></textarea>
            </div> 
       </form>
   </div>
```

and here is the jquery

```
$("#messageArea").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#userInput").submit();
    }
});

$("#userInput").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = $("#messageArea").val();
    if (message === ""){
        return;
    } else {
        $("#chatArea").append("<p id='chatmessage'>" + username + " : " + message + "</p>");
        $("#messageArea").val("");
    }
});
```

This is what it looks like with a long message.

[image: problem]

Also, notice the k's start on the next line, how can I make them start right after the colon. I'm using bootstrap by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `word-break: break-all;` to the element that contains the text that overflows.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Neat way to solve this. I think I prefer yours over mine, but I'll leave mine there just in case.

Comment: thnx, this worked, also is there any way to style the individual parts of each message. Like what if I wanted rockstar22 to be blue?

Comment: @Rockstar5645 In the jQuery, add to the class of the chatmessage `color:blue`.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 - I don't see that code in what you posted above.

Comment: @A. Abramov, that colors the entire paragraph, I only want Rockstar22 to be blue

Comment: You'd need to style your `username` variable. Typically you'd wrap it with a span and target that.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 Correct - you can seperate it then. Add two different parts - the sender, in it's own class which will have the color, and the message itself - just like Omegle. :)

Comment: @A. Abramov oh, yes, ofcourse, I don't know why that didn't occur to me, hehe

Answer (score 2):

Add to the Css of the div :`overflow:scroll`. that will add a scrolling bar whenever the text flows over the div. There are other parameters for the overflow trait which might work for you - you can read them [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

That'll make your HTML look like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="chatArea" style="overflow:scroll">
    </div>
    <form role="form" id="userInput">
        <button id="endChat" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Esc</button>
        <button id="sendMessage" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="messageArea"></textarea>
        </div> 
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends, i would use `overflow: hidden`. it will force the element to get bigger or in case that the element has a fixed height it will hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
word-break: break-all;
```

This allow the long words to break into peices to make it fit into dev;

Comment: Your answer looks identical to an existing answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `word-wrap: break-word` CSS property for that `div`. This forces word wrap for all words, including ones without proper breaking points (spaces, punctuation, etc).

```
#chatArea {
    word-wrap: break-word
}
```

[MDN reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)